# Error with 32-bit library installing Steam

Tags: steam

I am new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to install Steam on it, but I keep getting the error I need `libGL.so.1` 32bit library, and I can't install it manually I get more errors.

```
pablo@Negativo-BGH:~$ steam

(gnome-terminal:26512): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.

Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 needs to be installed

Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 needs to be installed

Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically

Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)

[2014-10-08 00:27:40] Startup - updater built Sep 22 2014 20:17:04

[2014-10-08 00:27:40] Verifying installation...

[2014-10-08 00:27:40] Verification complete

[2014-10-08 00:27:42] Shutdown

pablo@Negativo-BGH:~$
```

Comment: Have you tried installing libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 and libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 as it suggests? Do you get this error when installing the package or running Steam from a command-line interface like a Terminal with the steam command?

Comment: I'm getting a similar error on 14.04.2, it's driving me insane!! The packages don't seem to be in the repository. These things make me sad!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Ubuntu's website and go to alternative downloads
2. Find a download of the point release of 14.04.1
3. Reinstall ubuntu
4. Install steam, hey presto problem gone.

I'm no expert but it looks like they upgraded some packages for the 14.04.2 release that means steam can't find the dependencies to install correctly. If you need any expansion on these points let me know.